# How to stream and unzip large files in S3 with Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

How to unzip large files in AWS S3 without knowing the size beforehand and without keeping it all in memory or writing to disk?

Answer (score 0):

[nejckorasa/s3-stream-unzip](https://github.com/nejckorasa/s3-stream-unzip) manages unzipping of data in AWS S3 utilising stream download and multipart upload. It can run anywhere with access to S3 (including AWS Lambda), it uses Java S3 SDK library to connect to S3.

Unzipping is achieved without knowing the size beforehand and without keeping it all in memory or writing to disk. That makes it suitable for large data files - it has been used to unzip files of size 100GB+.

[nejckorasa/s3-stream-unzip](https://github.com/nejckorasa/s3-stream-unzip) is available in [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:%22io.github.nejckorasa%22%20AND%20a:%22s3-stream-unzip%22).